# Using Entity Framework Data First with ODBC and MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, odbc

How can I create a **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** using an ODBC connection to MySQL?

I installed MySQL 3.51 ODBC driver on my localhost, and I created a test MySQL database. Then  using VS2013 I create a data connection using ODBC Data Source to my test database. I can connect and Query that database.

[image: ODBC Connection to MySQL]

After all those steps before I couldn't created a **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** using an ODBC connection to MySQL. When I was adding the Data Model I did not have the option of use the ODBC Connection string or the option of creating a new connection string using ODBC datasource

[image: Creating a datasource]

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use ODBC with EF you will need to connect to the database and send SQL commads or call store procedures. The only way to use EF is connecting directing to the database use a connection string and valid permissions.